# SQL Pivot vs Case to reduce row count?

Tags: sql, pivot, case

I am writing a query to calculate win percentages on some game data.

My general query allows me to pull # of games and Wins to calculate %.
However it is broken down by:

- Game version (patch)
- Multiplayer Map
- Unit(Hero/Champion)
- Game Mode (AmmId)

The result set then returns roughly 200k rows. In theory there are multiple game modes and was wondering if it is worth the effort to pivot or make the Game Mode column data. And how would you do this?

Pivot seems to work great for singular column data not multiple. Also I could use case to filter columns by Game Mode.

What is the best approach for this?

```
SELECT  r.Version_GameVersionId, r.Map_MapId, p.[Hero_HeroId], 
gm.AmmId, Sum(Cast(p.Result as int)) as Wins, Count(p.ID) as Games

FROM [dbo].[Players] p
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Replays] r on r.ReplayId = p.Replay_ReplayId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[GameModes] gm on gm.GameModeId = r.GameMode_GameModeId
WHERE Map_Mapid = 54
Group by r.Map_MapId,p.[Hero_HeroId], r.Version_GameVersionId,gm.AmmId
order by r.Version_GameVersionId desc,r.Map_MapId,p.[Hero_HeroId]

Version_GameVersionId   Map_MapId   Hero_HeroId AmmId   Wins    Games
369                     54          1           50061   5       9
369                     54          1           50001   8       17
369                     54          1           50071   1       4
369                     54          1           50051   2       5
369                     54          2           50051   1       1
369                     54          2           50071   1       1
369                     54          2           50061   1       2
369                     54          2           50001   7       17
```